# Firefox incorrectly expands div height even when overflow is on

Tags: css, firefox, overflow

Works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. The div auto expanded when I did not want it to.
http://jsfiddle.net/s8d5v/

```
<div style="display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 200px;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
      <div style="display: block; overflow: auto; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
          <p>The height expands in Firefox, but not Chrome. It works correctly in Chrome when I want it to overflow.</p>

          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row; height: 40px; width: 100%; background: yellow;">
      bottom bar
  </div>

</div>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Change height:100%; to a fixed height in third div

```
<div style="display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 200px;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
      <div style="overflow: auto; height: 150px; width: 100%;">
          <p>The height expands in Firefox, but not Chrome. It works correctly in Chrome when I want it to overflow.</p>

          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row; height: 40px; width: 100%; background: yellow;">
      bottom bar
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I need it to take the full height of the parent container which is why I use 100% for the height. If not, I would have to separately write javascript to do a bunch of calculation.

Comment: Is your parent container dynamic

Comment: Yes. The first line (height: 200px) is actually dynamic. It is actually 100%, but I change it to 200px to demonstrate that Firefox expands the cell, but Chrome does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your `overflow:auto` div has auto height (because it's 100% of its parent cell, which has auto height), no?